# how to work with multiple Loggers in winston

Tags: nestjs, winston

I'm writing a backend using nestJS.
my application contains severl modules.
I want to use winston logger for debugging and productions levels.

So, I decided to use winston.loggers (as instructed [by winston 3 guide](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#working-with-multiple-loggers-in-winston))

Here a summary of my code :

(1) logger.js define a logger initiator :

```
const logFormatter = winston.format.printf((info) => {
    let { service, timestamp, level, stack, message } = info;
    message = stack || message;
    return `${timestamp} ${level} [${service}]: ${message}`;
});
export const initWinston = (apiTitle: string) => {
  const logger = winston.createLogger({
    defaultMeta: { service: apiTitle },
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
            level: 'info',
            format: winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.colorize(), 
                winston.format.simple(), 
                winston.format.timestamp(), 
                logFormatter),
                })
    ]});

  logger.info(`generated logger ${apiTitle}`)
  return(logger)
};
```

(2) in each module I using this initiator to push loger to winston.loggers pool.
for example: in PROJECT module it looks like this

```
winston.loggers.add('PROJECT', initWinston('PROJECT'))
```

since initWinston initiator contains logging an info message (for sanity check) It indeed print in correctly by the expected format (I see in the console a message like:
*2023-04-27T12:20:23.642Z info [PROJECT]: generated logger PROJECT*)

(3) within the module : in each controller I define private property *logger*, while the controller constructor set it from the winston.loggers

```
export class ProjectsController {
    private logger: winston.Logger=null;
    constructor(
        private projectService : ProjectsService) {
            this.logger = winston.loggers.get("PROJECT")
            this.logger.info("generated ProjectsController")
        };
};
```

The problem is that the line `this.logger.info("generated ProjectsController")`  in the controller constructor retruns in the console the following  message
*[winston] Attempt to write logs with no transports, which can increase memory usage: {"message":"generated ProjectsController","level":"info","service":"PROJECT"}*

I dont understand why the sanity check in step (2) works, but while pop the same logger from winston loggers (in step 3) it failed to find its console transprorter?